# Linking an .exe file in vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, exe

I'm working on a VisualBasic project (its my first), and I wanted to ask:

How can I link an .exe file with the project?

Example: When the user opens the project, the .exe file also opens.

Easy I think (I'm newbie!)

Comment: Are you saying that, when you open the solution in VS, you want to run a specific application? If so, may I ask to what end?

Comment: no i mean after i build  my app if a user open my app i want a specific app to run , i want to do that when i'm working the project before building

Comment: its like binding an app with my project

Comment: If you mean when the user runs your app, don't say when the user opens your project.  The compiled EXE is not a project.  There's no binding of any sort involved.  All you need is the path of a file to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start another application in your application, use Process.Start

Example:

```
Process.Start("C:\MyApplication.exe")
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: @randa187 If an answer sorts out your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to the answer - It makes sure that the user gets reputation points and makes it easier for anyone else who has the same problem to see that your question has an accepted answer that might work for them as well. (And the person answering the question gets reputation points btw)